# How to define new environment that wraps around linenomath

Tags: math-mode, environments

In order to assign proper line number for displayed equation, I need to wrap each displayed equation around

```
\begin{linenomath*}
\end{linenomath*}
```

I would like to define a new environment that wrap these two lines around

```
\begin{align*}
\end{align*}
```

etc.  Here is my *unsuccessful* attempt to implement this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amssymb,lineno}
\linenumbers

\newenvironment{myeqn}
    {
      \begin{linenomath*}
        \begin{align}
        \end{align}
      \end{linenomath*}
    }

\begin{document}

What I want

\begin{linenomath*}
  \begin{align}
    x^n + y^n &= z^n
\label{one}
  \end{align}
\end{linenomath*}

What I got

\begin{myeqn}
  x^n + y^n &= z^n
\label{two}
\end{myeqn}

\end{document}
```

What's the right way to implement this?  MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of works; at least, the output is the same (albeit disputable).

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amssymb,lineno}
\linenumbers

\newenvironment{myeqn}
 {\csname linenomath*\endcsname\align}
 {\endalign\csname endlinenomath*\endcsname}

\begin{document}

What I want
\begin{linenomath*}
  \begin{align}
    x^n + y^n &= z^n
\label{one}
  \end{align}
\end{linenomath*}

What I got

\begin{myeqn}
  x^n + y^n &= z^n
\label{two}
\end{myeqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When you wrap `align` in some other environment, you need to use the “inner form”, not with `\begin` and `\end`.

---

A generic environment where the desired one is given as argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amssymb,lineno}
\linenumbers

\NewDocumentEnvironment{linenodisplay}{mb}
 {\begin{linenomath*}\begin{#1}#2\end{#1}\end{linenomath*}}
 {}

\begin{document}

Here is \texttt{align}
\begin{linenodisplay}{align}
  x^n + y^n &= z^n \\
  x^n + y^n &= z^n
\end{linenodisplay}
and here is \texttt{align*}
\begin{linenodisplay}{align*}
  x^n + y^n &= z^n \\
  x^n + y^n &= z^n
\end{linenodisplay}
Also \texttt{equation}
\begin{linenodisplay}{equation}
a=b
\end{linenodisplay}
and \texttt{equation*}
\begin{linenodisplay}{equation*}
a=b
\end{linenodisplay}

\end{document}
```

You might need to add `\usepackage{xparse}` if your LaTeX release is earlier than 2020-10-01.

[image]

Comment: This answers the question I posted (thanks!),  but I realized belatedly that I also need a version for \begin{align*}\end{align*}.    When I modify your sample code by replacing \align  and \endalign by \align* and \endalign*  I  got gibbish results.  Might should I handle this new case?   Also, why did you say that "output is the same (albeit disputable)"?

Comment: @underflow `\csname align*\endcsname` and `\csname endalign*\endcsname`. Disputable is the double numbering…

Comment: @underflow I also added a generic form.

Comment: The generic form is most helpful.  The double number is a long-standing "feature" of lineno vs amslatex :-)